# Running jQuery on a mobile browser but not on a desktop browser

Tags: jquery, html

How do I run a jQuery script for a mobile phone browser but not for a desktop browser? I plan to use an accordion feature (expand/contract) to display content on the mobile browser but would like to show the expanded content on the desktop. I'm doing this to utilize screen space on the desktop and mobile device.

Comment: Thank you! I used JavaScript to measure the screen width (screen.width) and then expanded or collapsed the content accordingly. I'm not sure what problems I could run into in the future using this technique.

Comment: No problem dude, even though that's not responsive coding ;}

Answer (score 0):

if you're using asp you can use something like

```
<% if (Context.Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice) { %>
    <script src="/iosScript.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
<% } else { %>
    <script src="/normalScript.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
<% } %>
```

Comment: Thank you! Since I cant use ASP or PHP, I decided to use JavaScript to measure the screen width (screen.width) and then expand or collapse the content accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

This script is kind of long, but it will work. you can put your javasript tag inside the if mobile browser tag:

http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/lightweight-device-detection-php

Comment: Thank you! Since I cant use ASP or PHP, I used JavaScript to measure the screen width (screen.width) and then expanded or collapsed the content accordingly. I'm not sure what problems I could run into in the future using this technique.

Answer (score 0):

There's another way in javascript which is

```
    var mobile = (/iphone|ipad|ipod|android|blackberry|mini|windows\sce|palm/i.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase()));  
    if (mobile) {  
        //do something
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hsFfa/ <-- go to this link in both mobile and PC